# Appropriate relationship between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some inputs regarding the appropriate table structure and relationship
between my tables.
I have the following 3 tables:

Table 1

```
SeqId Version Date
1     V1      03-09-2018
```

Table 2

```
SeqId  TName Type
1      T1    local
1      T2    global
```

Table 3

```
SeqId TName Value Input
1     T1    90    dev
1     T1    80    qa
1     T2    70    prod
```

Here SeqId would be the primary key identity in table 1
I am not sure what keys in other table should I make. Shall I make SeqId & TName in table2, table3
as the foreign keys.

Inputs are appreciated

--Updated

SeqId is unique thats why I wanted to make it primary key in table1. 
Tname is not unique within a seq.

----Updated----

Would this be appropriate:

Table 1
SeqId as identity primary key

Table 2
SeqId as foreign key, Tname as primary key (tname is varchar - would it be fine creating it as primary key)

Table 3
SeqId as foreign key, Tname as foreign key, Value (this needs to be unique) as primary key

Comment: Are (SeqId, TName) unique?

Comment: seqid is uniqe, tname is not

Answer (score 0):

I would say the key as follows in normal case:
For Table 1, it is SeqId 
For Table 2, it is SeqId,TName 
For Table 3, it is SeqId,TName, Input 
But when you're defining the primary key or foreign key for tables in database system, it do based on the business requirement. Basically, what we really get by defining the keys are the default function which built in base database system to ensure data unique and consistence. 
Ex. when you define the SeqId as the primary key, system will usually return error when you're trying to insert a new record with the same SeqId.
Hope the info helps.

Comment: Table 1
SeqId as identity primary key

Table 2
SeqId as foreign key, Tname as primary key

Table 3
SeqId as foreign key, Tname as foreign key, Value as primary key